# R Regex : Need only numeric figures

Tags: regex, r

I'm working on R and using regex to keep only numeric figures in a column (I need to keep digits, negative and decimal sign).

Suppose I've a value

```
t = "$%-123,()@5./6 5ABC"
```

My expression

```
t1 = gsub("[^0-9+-.]", "", t )
```

returns

```
"-123,5.65"
```

Now to remove the comma (`,`) from the result  I've to write another line of code

```
t1 = gsub(",", "", t1)
```

Need help to simplify this so that this can be achieved in a single line of code.

Thanks.

Comment: To the down votes and close votes, I read all the requirements at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and there is only the *does the code work as intended* that could be debated. Here the OP deals with an unexpected result by writing more code to address the problem. So as a whole, I'd say his/her two lines of codes are working code achieving what's intended.

Comment: (@flodel: voting hints stress usefulness and clarity; one point to question is whether this post invites *insightful observation about the code* rather than tools used.) I think this question better fits the [topics of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your regex `[^0-9+-.]` in details and see why it does not replace commas:

- `[]` is for matching a character set
- `[^]` is to negate a character set, where you intend to match anything that is not one of the following characters (then replace with `""`):
- `0-9` defines a range of characters from `0` to `9` in the ascii table (char codes 48 to 57): `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`
- `+-.` defines a range of characters from `+` to `.` in the ascii table (char codes 43 to 46): `+`, `,`, `-`, `.`

It's this last item `+-.` that you did not mean to be interpreted as a range. Instead you wanted  `+`, `-`, and `.` to be interpreted as three separate characters. One solution is to switch their order so that `-` is not between two other characters and the regex engine won't see it as a range of characters: `+.-`  should work.

```
gsub("[^0-9+.-]","", t )
[1] "-1235.65"
```

Comment: This works well. Thanks for detailed explanation on why it was not working my way.